# How to move NIC to a different Vnet

Tags: azure

I need to move a NIC to a different Vnet. I deleted the VM, recreated it from disk in a new Vnet, but didn't find a way to attach the NIC. Is there a way to move it to the new Vnet so it can be attached? Alternatively is there a way to make the MAC address of the new NIC the same as that NIC? The reason I'm trying to do this is because we have a license server that checks the MAC address of the NIC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, you cannot move the nic, you can only delete it and recreate the nic in another vnet. I think you can just spoof the MAC address using OS capabilities.

Easily searchable on the web (search for linux\windows spoof mac address).